# Getting error during setup when doing "npm i wagmi viem"

Tags: metamask, wagmi, wagmi-hooks, wagmi-react

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: rpsls-bta@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"^4.9.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@">=5.0.4" from viem@1.18.1
npm ERR! node_modules/viem
npm ERR!   viem@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer viem@">=0.3.35" from wagmi@1.4.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/wagmi
npm ERR!     wagmi@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\rohan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rohan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-31T12_41_00_067Z-debug-0.log
```